# Error during compilation of OpenCV 3.0 with IPP and MinGW

Tags: windows, opencv3.0, intel-ipp

I'm trying to compile new stable OpenCV 3.0 on Windows 7 x64 with TBB 4.3, Qt 5.4.1, Eigen and IPP, that comes with OpenCV 3.0. I use MinGW 4.91. make stops with error on 50% with this message: "ld.exe: cannot find -lRunTmChk". If I uncheck WITH_IPP everything is OK. Is it possible to build OpenCV 3.0 with MinGW and IPP? Thank you!

Comment: "_I use MinGW 4.91_". That's a neat trick, since there is no such version of MinGW yet released. Perhaps you use mingw-w64 gcc-4.9.1, but mingw-w64 is _not_ MinGW, nor are the two associated in any way. Also, note that a version number of 4.91 is _not_ the same as 4.9.1, and GCC has certainly never had a 4.91 version release.

Comment: Sorry, I missed a dot, it's MinGW 4.9.1 of course. It is coming with Qt 5.4.1 installer

Comment: Well, even if it is gcc-4.9.1, it certainly _isn't_ MinGW, because the most recent version released by MinGW.org, (who own the MinGW trademark), is gcc-4.8.2. Please tag this properly: maybe `mingw-w64`; definitely _not_ `mingw`.